# Excel Is there a way to automatically add new rows with Formatting & Formulas from master sheet

Tags: excel

This may be a relatively easy question but I am not as savvy as my boss seems to think I am.

I'm currently building a spreadsheet to track wages, it is laid out with 5 sheets for time entry Monday - Friday, another sheet giving the costs and a final one that I want to be a master for updating staff details, pay rates etc.

Is there a way to set it up so that adding a new row in the master will add rows into the same location on the time entry sheets? Ideally without affecting the data already entered into those sheets?

I've tried using Powerquery but this doesn't keep the formulas I have in the cells and if a new row is added mid week it will clear the data already entered.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! I'd be glad to help but your question needs further clarification. For instance: if the 5 Mo-Fri sheets are for time *entry*, then why/how would they be affected by changes made in the Master sheet? What are the logical relationships between employees' time spent, costs, and pay rates? I suggest you make a static mock-up of your desired result and share it here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.